# How to change skin and make it persistant with an angularjs factory?

Tags: angularjs, factory

I want to create a form for the user to pick the skin he wants among a series.

I provide the factory Config to keep track of his choice thru routes.

The factory provides a way to save the config in cookies thru $scope.$watch('config.skin', function(){}) mechanism in order to preserve his choice thru multiple sessions.

The factory is as follows:

```
app.factory("Config",function($cookies){
    console.log("Factory Config…");
    return {
        config: {
            skin: "Gray"
        },
        save: function(s) {
            console.log("Config.save() "+mydump(s,2));
            this.config = s; 
            $cookies.config = JSON.stringify(this.config);
        },
        load: function() {
            if ($cookies.config) {
                try {
                    this.config = JSON.parse($cookies.config);
                    console.log("App controller: read config from cookies as: ");
                    for (var i in this.config) {
                        console.log ("— "+i+" = "+this.config[i]);
                    }
                } catch(e) {
                    config = null;
                }
            }
            if (!this.config) {
                this.config = {"skin": "Gray"};
                console.log("App controller: init config from controler ("+this.config+")");
            }
            return this;
        }
    };
});
```

The Config replaces the $scope.config in the controller.

The skin switching is provided thru a ng-class as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-class="{'skin{{config.skin}}':true}">
<!-- more html -->
</div>
```

Currently, though my ng-class is updated by the $scope.config.skin as expected, the class itself is not, though not achieving the execpected overall feature.

Any idea?

I've provided a fiddle that demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/SeUY7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolation won't work here. Instead, use:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-class="'skin' + config.skin">
```

[Working fork of your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uytF/)

Comment: Nice one.What made me confused is the fact I see ng-class bearing the right class in the inspector.

Comment: Very understandable. The problem is that a static string is just that - it doesn't change. When you use an expression which evaluates to a string, it remains dynamic.

Comment: But it changes actually… Inspect my original fiddle.

Comment: While trying to update my project, I see I oversimplified the fiddle. the ng-class must be a collection of classes. ng-class="{home:true, {true: 'skin' + config.skin}[true]:true}" (etc.) This breaks angular. Any additional idea?

Comment: Are all of the classes just `{'className': true}`?

Comment: Nope, almost all are like the skin way.

Comment: You can use an array (e.g. `ng-class="['skin' + config.skin, 'somethingelse' + anotherVar]"`)

Comment: Sounds like it does not want to (still looking into it): http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/SeUY7/13/

Comment: Gotcha, the line to blame is $scope.config = Config.load().config; where it should be $scope.config = Config.config; Thank you very much @Marc Kine!